# Adding space in text using core text in TTTAtributedLabel

Tags: iphone, ios5, uilabel, core-text

I am using TTTAtributedLabel in my app to make text bold and remaining as it is using custom fonts. Now I want to add some space of 5px between the bold and non bold text. How can I do this? I want to add space after 1.JANUAR 1934.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [CTRunDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreGraphics/Reference/CTRunDelegateRef/Reference/reference.html), and add it to your ns-attributed-string,

```
  CTRunDelegateCallbacks callbacks;
  callbacks.version = kCTRunDelegateCurrentVersion;
  callbacks.getAscent = ascentCallback;
  callbacks.getDescent = descentCallback;
  callbacks.getWidth = widthCallback;
  callbacks.dealloc = deallocCallback;
  spaceRunDelegate = CTRunDelegateCreate(&callbacks, NULL);

  spacingAttrs = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                (id)spaceRunDelegate, 
                (NSString*)kCTRunDelegateAttributeName,nil] retain];

  //add the attr to your ns-attributed-string
```